# How to make content appear before and after div

Tags: html, css

I want my content from `&:before` and `&:after` appear outside my `div.first` and before and after.

I thought the best way is using the css above, but it still appears inside my `div`, am I using the wrong method or is it something else?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uuL3sf6/1/

HTML

```
<div class="first">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.first
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;

  background-color:red;

  &:before
  {
    content:"before";
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
  }

   &:after
  {
    content:"after";
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo elements `:before` and `after` do not create content before and after their parent element. They are inserted before and after its actual content.

> A pseudo-element does exactly what the word implies. It creates a phoney element and inserts it before or after the content of the element that you’ve targeted.

<sup>From "[Learning To Use The :before And :after Pseudo-Elements In CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)"</sup>

That's why they are always displayed inside the box of their parent.

---

However, as an example you can use absolute positioning to move the pseudo element out of the box:

```
&:before {
    content:"before";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

But you can also `float` them or display them as `block` to achieve your desired result.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/qqg6w50c/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
  background-color:red;
 } 
  .first::before
  {
    content:"before";
   
  }
  
   .first::after
  {
    content:"after";
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="first">
</ br>  This is your first div. </ br>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e8qtoxL9/

```
.first
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  position: relative;

  &:before
  {
    content:"before";
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
   position: absolute;
 }

   &:after
  {
    content:"after";
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
   position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without SCSS: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvOeeM. Also, this  doesn't solve the problem.